# Google Scripts Forms - Update input validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, google-apps-script

I have a Google Form and an associated script (already connected via Deploy etc). The form serves as a sort of exam that is protected by a `Password`. The idea is to regenerate this `Password` with a code after each `Submit` and to replace the old `Password` with `newPassword`. However, I get this code here and ask for help.

[image]

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  console.log('Form submission received.');

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var response = e.response;
  var items = form.getItems();

  // Find the password input field by its title
  var passwordFieldTitle = 'Password';
  var passwordField = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].getTitle() === passwordFieldTitle) {
      passwordField = items[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (passwordField === null) {
    console.log('Password field not found.');
    return;
  }

  // Get the password input value
  var itemResponses = response.getItemResponses();
  var passwordInputValue = null;

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    if (itemResponses[j].getItem().getTitle() === passwordFieldTitle) {
      passwordInputValue = itemResponses[j].getResponse();
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!passwordInputValue) {
    console.log('Password field value is missing.');
    return;
  }

  // Generate a new password
  var newPassword = generatePassword();

  // Update the input validation for the password field
  var validation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
    .setHelpText('Please enter the new password as displayed in the form help text.')
    .requireTextContains('New Password: ' + newPassword)
    .build();

  passwordField.asTextItem().setValidation(validation);

  // Check if the password matches the stored password
  var isValidPassword = passwordInputValue.includes('New Password: ' + newPassword);

  if (!isValidPassword) {
    console.log('Invalid password. Please try again.');
    form.setCustomClosedFormMessage('Invalid password. Please try again.');
    return;
  }

  // Send a Discord webhook with the new password
  sendDiscordWebhook(newPassword);
}

function generatePassword() {
  var length = 12; // Length of the password
  var characters =
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789&@/-?'; // Allowed characters for the password
  var password = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    password += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
  }

  return password;
}

function sendDiscordWebhook(password) {
  console.log('Sending Discord webhook with the new password.');

  var payload = {
    embeds: [
      {
        title: 'New Password',
        description: 'The password has been changed.',
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'Password',
            value: password,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordWebhookUrl, options);

  console.log('Discord webhook sent successfully.');
}
```

[1] This is the `Password` which is to be replaced with `newPassword` after submit

[image]

How can I solve this? I've already tried other things like `RegEx`, but I'd better stay away from `RegEx` ;)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: Result: Input Validation changes to newPassword

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requireTextContains` is not a valid method for "Forms".

Use instead:

- `requireTextContainsPattern()` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder#requiretextcontainspatternpattern), or
- `requireTextMatchesPattern` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder#requiretextmatchespatternpattern)

Since this is a password, I'd put my money on `requireTextMatchesPattern`

Comment: As I said, I do not really want to use RegRex, since I dont really understand it. Could you give an example for how a Pattern that matches the random generated password?

Comment: would .requireTextMatchesPattern('.*' + newPassword + '.*') make the deal?